# Printing elements of array in one line in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, printing, puts

I have got the following Ruby hash:

```
hash = {
0 => "
===
@@@
@ @
@ @
@ @
@@@
===",
1 => "
=
@
@
@
@
@
="}
```

I would like to print out some of the values of the hash in one line in the console.
To that effect, I have created an array with the elements I would like printed out:

```
test = [hash[0], hash[1]]
```

or

```
test1 = [hash[0], hash[0]]
```

In case I want to print `test1` to the console, the result should be the following:

```
======
@@@@@@
@ @@ @
@ @@ @
@ @@ @
@@@@@@
======
```

In case I want to print `test2 to the console, the result should be:

```
====
@@@@
@ @@
@ @@
@ @@
@@@@
====
```

However, when I use `puts` or `print`, the result is always that one is printed after another and not in the same line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a two-dimensional structure first to be able to get the wanted result.

I suggest the following steps:

1. Deconstruct the values in your `hash`

   ```
   atomic = hash.values.map{ |e| e.split("\n")}
   ```

   This will give you

   ```
   [["",
     "===",
     "@@@",
     "@ @",
     "@ @",
     "@ @",
     "@@@",
     "==="
    ], [
     "",
     "=",
     "@",
     "@",
     "@",
     "@",
     "@",
     "="
    ]]
   ```
2. Use the new data structure to build the output you need

   first case:

   ```
   test1 = atomic[0].zip(atomic[0]).map(&:join)
   puts test1
   ```

   =>

   ```
   ======
   @@@@@@
   @ @@ @
   @ @@ @
   @ @@ @
   @@@@@@
   ======
   ```

   second case:

   ```
   test2 = atomic[0].zip(atomic[1]).map(&:join)
   ```

   =>

   ```
   ====
   @@@@
   @ @@
   @ @@
   @ @@
   @@@@
   ====
   ```

I hope you find that helpful.

Comment: Your answer seems to be the same as my earlier answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have implemented what you suggested and, in fact, they are now printing in the same line. However, they are printing with some space between each other. You can see ir here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1udhbQQMqJWs-S7Ze7-byZxdMKRwMJllc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @franciscofcosta, I realized that I found the same solution after I posted it. I think Cary and i have been typing our answers at the same time, he was simply faster :-).

I can't see where the spaces come from. For me `test1` looks like this: `["", "======", "@@@@@@", "@ @@ @", "@ @@ @", "@ @@ @", "@@@@@@", "======"]` (no spaces here), could you post your `test1.inspect` so we work backwards to find the issue?

Comment: Hi @knugie, thanks for the reply. I just did `test1.inspect` and I get this: `["", "    ===    ===", "    @@@    @@@", "    @ @    @ @", "    @ @    @ @", "    @ @    @ @", "    @@@    @@@", "    ===    ==="]`. As you can see, it's not exactly the same as you have. I've got spaces in the second and last elements of the array.

Comment: I see what the issue is now. in your original post, the trailing spaces have been removed automatically. That's why Cary and I didn't see them. I see two sensible options of fixing that. First, remove the trailing white spaces in your original `hash` before processing it. And second, `strip` trailing whitespace of each line like so: `atomic = hash.values.map{ |e| e.split("\n").map(&:strip)}`. Does that help?

Comment: Because there are only trailing whitespaces but no leading ones, you could use `chomp` instead of `strip` - your choice.

Comment: Thank you! I was on my way to write the exact same thing. Thanks so much for your help! If I had more than 2 elements in the hash, would I be able to combine them the same way? Let's say if I had a `test3` that I would like to show up after `test2`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 5):

```
a1, a2 = hash.values.map { |s| s[1..-1].split("\n") }
  #=> [["===", "@@@", "@ @", "@ @", "@ @", "@@@", "==="],
  #    ["=", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "="]]
```

```
puts a1.zip(a1).map(&:join)
======
@@@@@@
@ @@ @
@ @@ @
@ @@ @
@@@@@@
======
```

```
puts a1.zip(a2).map(&:join)
====
@@@@
@ @@
@ @@
@ @@
@@@@
====
```

Note:

```
a1.zip(a1)
  #=> [["===", "==="], ["@@@", "@@@"], ["@ @", "@ @"], ["@ @", "@ @"],
  #    ["@ @", "@ @"], ["@@@", "@@@"], ["===", "==="]]

a1.zip(a2)
  #=> [["===", "="], ["@@@", "@"], ["@ @", "@"], ["@ @", "@"],
  #    ["@ @", "@"], ["@@@", "@"], ["===", "="]]
```

`s[1..-1]`, which drops the first character of `hash[0]` and `hash[1]`, is needed because that character is a newline (`"\n"`). Had the two lines `0 => "` and `===` been written `0 =>"===` (similar for `hash[1]`), I could have written `s.split("\n")`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have implemented what you suggested and, in fact, they are now printing in the same line. However, they are printing with some space between each other. You can see ir here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1udhbQQMqJWs-S7Ze7-byZxdMKRwMJllc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know why are you getting that result. I used your data (`hash`) and my code to produce the desired result, which I show. First confirm that you are using the hash `hash` given in your question. If you haven't done so, cut-and-paste the expression `hash = { ... }`, then run the code.

Comment: Yes, I am using the exact same hash.

Comment: When you execute `a1, a2 = hash.values.map { |s| s[1..-1].split("\n") }` do you get the same return value as that shown in my answer? If you do, do you get the same return value as I show for `a1.zip(a1)`?